# Sonarqube LDAP Group Filter not working

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

I am running Sonarqube 6.7.1.35068 on Windows Server 2016 with LDAP plugin 2.2.  I have LDAP working, as new users are able to log into Sonarqube with their domain credentials and create an account, but my group filter is not working.  I am trying to filter logins based on a specific AD security group membership, but unfortunately all users on the domain are able to login, as the group filtering is not working.  The following is my LDAP configuration in the properties file:

```
#----- LDAP configuration
# General Configuration
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
sonar.authenticator.downcase=true
ldap.url=ldap://ldap.domain.com:3268
ldap.bindDn=serviceaccount@ad.domain.com
ldap.bindPassword=********

# User Configuration
ldap.user.baseDn=dc=ad,dc=domain,dc=com
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail

# Group Configuration
ldap.group.baseDn=CN=Sonarqube,OU=Software Access,OU=Security Groups,OU=AD Groups,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=com
ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=group)(memberOf={dn}))
ldap.group.idAttribute=sAMAccountName
```

I have tried several different combinations for the **ldap.group.baseDn** and
**ldap.group.request** values, but have not had any success with user filtering based on AD group membership. There unfortunately are no good specific detailed examples on how to configure these 2 values for Sonarqube.  Anyone?

Comment: You expect your LDAP filtering to not match and thus not authenticate users who are not members of certain groups?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  If a user is a member of the Sonarqube AD security group, then they are allowed to login to Sonarqube.  If a user is not a member of the Sonarqube AD security group, then they are not allowed to login to Sonarqube.

Comment: Then this isn't related to SonarQube as such, is it?

Comment: It is related to the syntax required in the LDAP group configuration for Sonarqube.  I have this working in all of my Engineering solutions (JIRA, Jenkins, etc.).  I need clarification on the required syntax to successfully filter users based on AD group membership using Sonarqube LDAP group configuration.  The docs provided do not provide the necessary details.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks, Jeroen.  I'm fairly good with LDAP syntax, it is the variations expected between applications.  For example, I am able to group filter in JIRA, so I know my LDAP syntax is technically correct, but the same syntax does not work when applied to Sonarqube.  My goal of this thread is for someone to post a real world configuration where they used AD group filtering by defining a specific AD group.  I am still yet to see one, and am not sure it is even possible to filter by group, but rather you can only filter by OU which is a user configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Group configuration is not required. You can restrict SonarQube access based on a specific LDAP/AD group membership by restricting the user-filter option on the ldap.user.request:

> ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login})(memberOf=CN=ldap-group,OU=groups,DC=example,DC=com))

My final working config is as follows:

```
#----- General Configuration
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
sonar.authenticator.downcase=true
ldap.url=ldap://ldap.domain.com:3268
ldap.bindDn=serviceaccount@ad.domain.com
ldap.bindPassword=********

#----- User Configuration
ldap.user.baseDn=dc=ad,dc=domain,dc=com
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login})(memberOf=CN=ldap-group,OU=groups,DC=example,DC=com))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail
```

Answer (score 1):

Also running Sonarqube 6.7.1 on Windows Server 2016 with LDAP plugin 2.2
The group filter configuration was the tricky part, for me it works like that:

```
# User Configuration
ldap.user.baseDn=DC=lan,DC=domain,DC=de
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
ldap.user.LastNameAttribute=sn
ldap.user.firstNameAttribute=givenName
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))

# Group Configuration
ldap.group.baseDn=DC=lan,DC=domain,DC=de
ldap.group.idAttribute=cn
ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=group)(member={dn}))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Rebse.  Looking over your configuration, I can't locate where the group is defined, meaning location in AD, I would have expected a deifinitive group mapping to be either in ldap.group.baseDn or ldap.group.request.  Where did you define the AD group?  For example, I'm trying to group filter by defining my group as such "CN=Sonarqube,OU=Software Access,OU=Security Groups,OU=AD Groups,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=com" in my ldap.group.baseDn value.

Comment: @MarkConway Ok, now i understand. Thought you had problems to get the groups at all. But the problem seems "only" to get the right baseDn setting, though i see differences, f.e. i have ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=group)(member={dn})) you have
ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=group)(memberOf={dn}))

Comment: @MarkConway Just had a look at an Applicationgroup in our AD, your Setting seems right, but the users are beyond member, whereas memberOf has the group(s) this group is nested in, means try with ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=group)(member={dn}))